# Fast load data from Kafka to MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-kafka, pyodbc

I have read data from Kafka and now I will need to load data to the MSSQL server.

I have tried a few methods.

This method load only 500 rows by 1 minutes:

```
while max_offset < end_offset-1:
    msg = consumer.poll() 
    max_offset += 1
if msg is not None:
    if msg.error():
        print(f'Error while receiving message: {msg.error()}')
    else:
        value = msg.value()
        offset = msg.offset()
        try: 
            cursor = conn_str.cursor()
            df = pd.json_normalize(value)
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4, COLUMN_5, COLUMN_6) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", row.column_1, row.column_2, row.column_3, row.column_4, row.column_5, row.column_6)
                conn_str.commit()
            
                print(f'Received message:\n{df}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error message: {e}')
else:
    print('No messages received')
```

The second method which I tried, was :

```
messages_to_insert = []
batch_size = 10000
counter = 0

while max_offset < end_offset-1:
    msg = consumer.poll()
    max_offset += 1
    if msg is not None:
        if msg.error():
           
        else:
         
            row = msg.value()
            offset = msg.offset()
         
            messages_to_insert.append((row["field1"], row["field2"], row["field3"], row["field4"], row["field5"], row["field6"]))
            counter += 1
           
            if counter >= batch_size:
                cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO <table_name> (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", messages_to_insert)
                conn_str.commit()
                messages_to_insert = []
                counter = 0

if messages_to_insert:
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO <table_name> (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", messages_to_insert)
    conn_str.commit()
```

It method a little bit faster.

And the last one was loaded to a .csv file.
To  .csv file loads very fast, but a load to mssql is too slow

```
messages_to_insert = []
batch_size = 10000
counter = 0

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['COLUMN_1', 'COLUMN_2', 'COLUMN_3', 'COLUMN_4', 'COLUMN_5', 'COLUMN_6'])

    while max_offset < end_offset-1:
        msg = consumer.poll()
        max_offset += 1
        if msg is not None:
            if msg.error():
                logger.error(f'Error while receiving message: {msg.error()}')
            else:
                row = msg.value()
                offset = msg.offset()

                # Write row to file
                writer.writerow([row['field1'], row['field2'], row['field3'], row['field4'], row['field5'], field6])

file_path = 'data.csv'


with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines.pop(0)
data = [tuple(line.strip().split(',')) for line in lines]
placeholders = ','.join('?' * len(data[0]))


    query = f"INSERT INTO <table_name> (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4, COLUMN_5, COLUMN_6) VALUES ({placeholders})"


    cursor = conn_str.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(query, data)
    cursor.commit()

conn.close()
```

And tried load to a .csv file after this using SSIS, but the load speed was the same.

[image]

Comment: You can try SSIS **Bulk Insert** Task.

Comment: What is it you are *actually* asking here? There isn't a question in your question.

Comment: @ThomA how make load faster, it is my question

Comment: All of your attempts appear to be using RBAR methods, @Denys , you `INSERT` one row by agonising row. SSIS, however, should be pretty quick as it'll batch the data into a transaction. How long is "too long"? How long are these processes *actually* taking?

Comment: @ThomA SSIS takes about 15 minutes to load 10,000 rows, python is about the same speed.  but topic Kafka can have millions of records and therefore the speed that is currently seems to me slow.  into the csv file itself, loading from Kafka is very fast

Comment: Do you have something like a poorly written trigger on your table? *Far* too many indexes? 15 minutes to insert 10,000 rows screams that there is a more significant problem.

Comment: there are no triggers or indexes, the most common table

Comment: If you want it to be faster, don't use Python... You can use Kafka Connect JDBC Sink for this. Or, if you need Python, do not create a one-row dataframe for every consumed event. CSV files will also be slow

Comment: @OneCricketeer Unfortunately I can't use Kafka Connect JDBC Sink, I will try butch load

Comment: Yes, batch loading is the best you can do (JDBC Sink does the same). However, you need to disable Kafka consumer auto offset-commits and also use transactions (which you currently don't have), among other error handling. Still, Python will be slower than other languages like Java, C#, Go, etc.

Comment: @OneCricketeer At this moment I`m trying to use sqlalchemy for batch loading

Comment: Okay. As mentioned, you'll also want to use transactions https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_transaction.html

Comment: `but the load speed was the same.` something's wrong with your code, database or the way you measure time. 10Krows is no data at all and *definitely* doesn't require 1 minute. Even 1 second would be too much. Slight delays should be noticeable at 1M rows. Perhaps the disk is slow, there are no indexes, the table is locked by other transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works fine for me:

```
values_list.append(decoded_msg)

if len(values_list) == 10000:
    df = pd.DataFrame(values_list)
    column_order = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
    df = df.reindex(columns=column_order)
   
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        
        print(df)
        try:
            df.to_sql('TABLE_NAME', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'COL1': Integer(), 'COL2': String(), 'COL3': String()}, schema='SCHEMA')
        except Exception as e:
            print("An error occurred while inserting data: ", e)
        connection.commit()

    values_list = []
```

Comment: That's *slow* code, the exact opposite of an SSIS bulk import task. `to_sql` insers rows one by one (unless you enabled `fastexecutemany`) in a fully-logged manner. BULK INSERT, bcp and SSIS bulk import use minimal logging, where only the data pages are logged, not individual INSERTs. Loading the CSV data into a dataframe is even slower - first you have to load all data in memory, then you have to send it to the database

Comment: The *fast* way to load data is to use the `bcp` command or `BULK INSERT` SQL command to import the data directly from a CSV or flat file. 10K rows is no data at all, it could easily fit into the CPU cache

Comment: When creating the engine I added parameter
`engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params), fast_executemany=True)`

Comment: That's still the slow way. There's absolutely no way just 10K lines would take even a minute without serious problems. What's going on with the server? Did you check `Activity Monitor`? Are there blocked sessions? Is the target table used by other connections at the same time which would result in blocking? If you import directly into a busy table that doesn't have appropriate indexes, any `SELECT` command can easily take Shared locks on the entire table. Your `INSERT`s have to wait for the locks to be released.  Have you tried importing the data into a separate staging table?